Where are Atom's 'Untitled' files stored?
I have a few 'Untitled' files in an Atom project. How can I recover the files without opening Atom?
I have ignored the sunsetting of the project assuming the app would continue to open. However, the application now fails to load on my computer. So I need to find the location of 'Untitled' files on disk.

Those files are likely stored outside of Atom Editor's trees, and I believe Pulsar uses different project and environment settings so it could not recover the files either.

@MatthewSchuchard Thanks, I went on the Pulsar Discord and someone helped me migrate the data from Atom to Pulsar.

With the help of DeeDeeG on the Pulsar Discord; you can migrate from Atom to Pulsar by copying ~/.atom and ~/.config/Atom to ~/.pulsar and ~/.config/Pulsar respectively.

Install Pulsar.

Ensure both ~/.pulsar and ~/.config/Pulsar do not exist.
sudo rm -r ~/.pulsar
sudo rm -r ~/.config/Pulsar


Copy the files across.

Native Atom -> Native Pulsar
cp -r ~/.atom        ~/.pulsar \
cp -r ~/.config/Atom ~/.config/Pulsar


Flatpak Atom -> Native Pulsar
cp -r ~/.var/app/io.atom.Atom/data        ~/.pulsar \
cp -r ~/.var/app/io.atom.Atom/config/Atom ~/.config/Pulsar




Load up Pulsar.



Additionally a script exists to dump all 'Untitled' files -- which may work in Pulsar, and help with making the files normal files.

There should be no need to use sudo when deleting files in the home-folder and nobody should be encouraged to use it.

@idleberg Ok, well from what I recall some files were marked as system files and so using sudo means you don't have to spam y. If you want to spam y then be my guest.
